# Using Rcpp and RInside in Windows 7 Without Specific IDEs

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

Most of the people who have asked about this topic so far seem to be either halfway through the process of installing these packages (whereas I barely know how to begin) or are using things like Eclipse + StatEt, which I'd like to avoid unless absolutely necessary. I have attempted to read through the Rcpp FAQ and Introduction, but owing to my relative lack of computing knowledge (see next paragraph), I found neither too helpful in my quest to install these packages.

Currently I use the g++ compiler via cygwin to compile C++ code, and nothing more complicated than the basic R interface (the one that comes with the download) for using R. I have not yet used an R package more difficult to install than using the standard `install.packages()` command or any C++ code from a source other than the Standard Library or files that I have made myself. In addition, if it makes a difference, I have never created a R package or a C++ package for myself. My experience with C++ is at about the level of someone who's taken a single semester's worth of programming in that language, and I primarily use R as a "statistics package" as opposed to a "programming language".

So basically I'm looking for a clear, concise way to understand how to install and use these packages, or, failing that, links to information about additional things I need to understand about computing before being capable of using them.

Some terms that I have encountered in my adventure thus far that I do not understand are:

- "make" / "makefile" (assuming they refer to the same thing)
- binaries, and how they differ from normal files
- "building from source"

If it is impossible to understand the installation process without knowing these terms, then any advice on what these terms mean would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You write

> Currently I use the g++ compiler via cygwin to compile C++

which is plainly not supported at all by R. You can only use the MinGW compiler provided by Rtools.

You also write

> So basically I'm looking for a clear, concise way to understand how to
>   install and use these packages

There really are a lot of tutorials out there for package building with R. Please pick one you like, and read it thoroughly.  Then come back with specific questions.

All Rcpp / RInside examples work with the respective `Makefile.win` files.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page: My impression is that once I have Rcpp working, then I can start to worry about building packages with C++ code for myself. My problem is in the first step (getting it working) rather than the second (building my own packages with it), because setting it up seems more involved than is usual for R packages. For example, most pieces of example code I see involving Rcpp are in C++ and use `#include <Rcpp.h>`. Where can I find Rcpp.h? It isn't on my computer after doing `install.packages('Rcpp')` (I didn't expect it to be, but I searched just in case).

Comment: It should be in library\Rcpp\include. You probably used Windows search, which does not search the program directories by default to avoid "confusing the public". For things like this, install "Search Everything".

Comment: @DieterMenne just to complement , some more parent directories: Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\library\Rcpp\include